# Uso específico del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo

Tags: subjuntivo

Tengo una pregunta que haceros. Acabo de leer una frase en la que se usa el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo aunque no me parece necesario o gramáticamente correcto hacerlo:

> "La única forma de evitar dar vueltas indefinidamente en una hélice esférica es que ésta **fuera** arquimediana."

¿Me podéis explicar (en español o en inglés) por qué se usa el imperfecto de subjuntivo aquí en lugar del presente de subjuntivo? "...es que **sea** arquimediana" a mí me suena mejor.

¡Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se trata de un error. Los tiempos verbales están, como ya notaste, descoordinados. La idea podría expresarse de dos maneras correctas:

- Con una combinación de presente de indicativo y presente de subjuntivo:

> *"La única forma de evitar dar vueltas indefinidamente en una hélice esférica **es** que ésta **sea** arquimediana."*

- Con una combinación de condicional e imperfecto de subjuntivo:

> *"La única forma de evitar dar vueltas indefinidamente en una hélice esférica **sería** que ésta **fuera** arquimediana."*

Ambas formas son gramaticalmente correctas y significan lo mismo. La primera, que está en presente, es más general y abstracta, como corresponde a una realidad lógica o matemática. La segunda es más adecuada a una situación particular, pero éste no parece ser el caso. Yo usaría la primera.

Comment: Vale, gracias por tu explicación y que tengas un buen día!